# Ignoring unnecessary object properties brought along with a Back-End object

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-entity

Have a question on ignoring unnecessary object properties brought along with a Back-End model.

Can you plz provide your inputs ?

Let us say that an API is returning below object

```
export class TodoObject{

public name: string;

public id: number,

public assignedTo:string,

public completed: boolean,

public dueDate:Date

}
```

In Angular UI I do not require the below two fields

```
public assignedTo:string,

public dueDate:Date
```

so can i have an object in Angular UI as below ?

```
export class TodoObject{

public name: string;

public id: number

public completed: boolean

}
```

Is it possible to do this in Angular. I know GraphQL has capability for this. Wanted to know if its is possible to achieve this.

Is this possible using Ngrx or other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually map the properties.

```
const frontEndModel = {
  name: backendModel.name,
  id: backendModel.id,
  completed: backendModel.completed
}
```